# How to handle single output multiple losses in keras?

Tags: keras

My model has a single output. But I want to separate the loss into 3 different components so that I can track the progress of each. Is there a way to do this with keras?

Maybe I could define the same loss components as metrics but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem.. Did you get the solution to it?

Comment: here a simple solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62861773/can-we-use-multiple-loss-functions-in-same-layer/62862033#62862033

Answer (score 4):

You can define the losses as Keras layers and then you can add all of your losses and metrics (if you want) manually.

[You can see a complete tutorial about this topic here](https://gaborvecsei.wordpress.com/2018/10/15/implement-loss-functions-inside-keras-models/)

TL;DR:

- Define layers where you calculate the loss
- Write your own compile() function where you add the optimizer, and the losses and the metrics
- At model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=...) add `None` as loss

This is how manually adding the losses looks like in code:

```
loss_layer_names = {"my_loss", ...}

# Adding losses
for name in loss_layer_names:
    layer = model.get_layer(name)
    loss = (tf.reduce_mean(layer.output, keepdims=True))
    model.add_loss(loss)

# Adding metrics
for name in loss_layer_names:
    layer = model.get_layer(name)
    loss = (tf.reduce_mean(layer.output, keepdims=True))
    model.metrics_names.append(name)
    model.metrics_tensors.append(loss)

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=[None] * len(model.outputs))
```

Where `model` is a Keras model